# Windows 10: how to configure multiple monitors by script

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors

Before anyone asks if this has been asked before, it has, but I haven't found a recent enough and/or satisfactory answer, so I hope the situation has changed.

I have 3 monitors (well, 2 + TV) and need to switch between them often enough that the default Windows GUI way (which involves about 10 clicks, some scrolling and some waiting) is getting on my nerves. This is on a home PC runnign Windows 10 Pro if relevant.

There are two setups that I need to toggle between, see image:

[Display setups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oIyf.png)

Case one: **display 1**: main, 2560x1440 **display 2**: disconnected **display 3**: 1920x1080, rotated by 90°, extending desktop

Case two: **display 1**: main, 1920x1080 **display 2**: duplicating 1 **display 3**: disconnected

I want to have a short script that would on execution simply toggle between the two configutation, so that I would reduce all that configuration to a single doubleclick from desktop. I expected there would be something that would allow me to select a display by its Windows-assigned ID and set its properties the way I have summed up above. Surely if you can do it via clicking in the GUI, there must be a way to do it via command line? But I found none.

There is the MS displayswitch.exe tool which is way too basic for this case.

An often recommended tool is the MultiMonitor Tool from Nirsoft. In my experience it fails at this because it seems unable to set display as duplicate, and also it seems to get confused which display is which. I tried saving both configurations while they were active and then loading them, and it botches the job, ending up with something completely different.

Comment: You might try Nirsoft's RegistryChangesView, https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registry_changes_view.html , to create a .reg file for each configuration, There are *many* conflicting statements on the web about *which* keys to use, so do it empirically.

Answer (score 1):

To save Windows desktop settings and elements, you can use Windows Desktop icon saving tools.
[**DesktopOK**](https://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Freeware/DesktopOK) tool is convenient and has many useful settings.